# How can i sort the list with keys in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have the two list dictionary like this

```
obj1 = [mydict['obj1'],mydict['obj2'],mydict['obj3'],mydict['obj4']]  
obj2 = [mydict['obj1'],mydict['obj2'],mydict['obj3'],mydict['obj4'], mydict['obj5'] ]
```

Now i want that

1. Count the number of elements in each list
2. Then based on whichever is greater then get that list of objects

I want a single list which conatins the above two list of(list of) dictionaries based on the higher number of elements so that i cause something like this

```
mylist = myfunc(objects1, objects2  )
```

mylist should be a list like `[objects1, objects2]` depending upon who has greater number of objects.

what is the best way to do that with less lines of code

Something like EDIT

```
mylist = sorted([obj1, obj2], key=lambda a: len(a), reverse=True)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your first code block at all. Can you write an example that is valid Python code?

Comment: You should try writing some actual code first.  Plus, I think you're confusing "list" with "dictionary."

Comment: You want less than _one line_ of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a lambda function if it's just going to call a function anyway.

```
>>> objects1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> objects2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> 
>>> mylist = [objects1, objects2]
>>> max(mylist, key=len)
['1', '2', '3', '4']

>>> sorted(mylist, key=len, reverse=True)
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objects1 = [1, 2, 3]
objects2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

mylist = [objects1, objects2]
mylist.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
print mylist

[['1', '2', '3', '4'], [1, 2, 3]]
```